# How to resize a path?

Tags: android, path, resize, image-manipulation

I'm trying to do an app in Android that work with finger paint and that must be able to manage the zoom. So I have an image in the background and I draw over it, but when I zoom in and out, I have to resize both the image and the path drawn and I don't know how. I used the code of Zdnet to implement the [pinch to zoom gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847) and it works great for the background image, so I thought that the only step to make the "path resize" was to put mPath.transform(matrix) at the end of onTouch(), but it  doesn't allow me to draw properly and does not resize the path.
How could I do it?

Note: the code to implement the finger paint is [that of Google](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html).

Comment: Take a look here. It's an example about how translate e resize a path by touch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15252369/736196

Answer (score 0):

mPath.transform should work, it's hard to tell what's wrong without code.

Alternatively, you could use Canvas.scale if you want to scale everything drawn by the same factor.