# Android Drawing Path while Zoom and Pinch

Tags: android, path, matrix, bitmap

I'm drawing bitmap and trying to do some drawing over it using Canvas.for drawing i'm adding 
path whenever user draw something on it surface. I have implemented pinch Zoom and drag features over bitmap but when user Zoom the bitmap and draw something on it then Path doesn't get draw appropriately. I'm using Matrix for pinch zoom and drag features.
My problem is using the Path with with Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example where you can see how to implement a draggable and zoomable Path:

MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class DrawActivity extends Activity {

        DrawView drawView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set full screen view
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            drawView = new DrawView(DrawActivity.this);

            setContentView(drawView);
        }    
}
```

DrawView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class DrawView extends View {

    Context ctx;

    static final String TAG = "DrawView";

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    //These two constants specify the minimum and maximum zoom
    private static float MIN_ZOOM = 3f;
    private static float MAX_ZOOM = 10f;

    private float scaleFactor = 3.f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector detector;

    //These two variables keep track of the X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first
    //touches the screen
    private float startX = 0f;
    private float startY = 0f;

    //These two variables keep track of the amount we need to translate the canvas along the X
    //and the Y coordinate
    private float translateX = 0f;
    private float translateY = 0f;

    //These two variables keep track of the amount we translated the X and Y coordinates, the last time we
    //panned.
    private float previousTranslateX = 0f;
    private float previousTranslateY = 0f; 

    private boolean dragged = false;

// Used for set first translate to a quarter of screen
    private float displayWidth;
    private float displayHeight;

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        ctx = context;

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        display.getMetrics(metrics);

        displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

        translateX = displayWidth/4;
        translateY = displayHeight/4; 

        previousTranslateX = displayWidth/4;
        previousTranslateY = displayHeight/4;

        detector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);       

// Path's color
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setAntiAlias(false); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {     
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();

        //We're going to scale the X and Y coordinates by the same amount
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);

        //We need to divide by the scale factor here, otherwise we end up with excessive panning based on our zoom level
        //because the translation amount also gets scaled according to how much we've zoomed into the canvas.
        canvas.translate((translateX) / scaleFactor, (translateY) / scaleFactor);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);

        canvas.restore(); 

    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

// First finger is on screen

            //We assign the current X and Y coordinate of the finger to startX and startY minus the previously translated
            //amount for each coordinates This works even when we are translating the first time because the initial
            //values for these two variables is zero.
            startX = event.getX() - previousTranslateX;
            startY = event.getY() - previousTranslateY;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

// first finger is moving on screen  
// update translation value to apply on Path

            translateX = event.getX() - startX;
            translateY = event.getY() - startY;             

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

// No more fingers on screen

            // All fingers went up, so let's save the value of translateX and translateY into previousTranslateX and
            //previousTranslate
            previousTranslateX = translateX;
            previousTranslateY = translateY;
            break;

// All touch events are sended to ScaleListener
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;
    }   

    class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {


            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }   
    }
}
```